# when i created second empty activity then there came a floating button so can you tell me how to remove floating button in android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio

i know how to remove it in 2.2.3 and all i want to know how to remove it in ndroid studio 3.1.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove it from created layout for activity like `activity_main.xml`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2">

Comment: Just search for FloatingActionButton all the project by pressing ‘ctrl+shift+f‘ and remove it:)